# Moving data to the next sheet without the header

Tags: vba, excel

Moving data to the next sheet without the header. The Data is moving with the header. I'm trying to leave the header and copy the data only to another sheet.

```
Sub cmdButtonData_Click()

    SellStartDate = Sheets("Start").Range("H10").Value   
    SellEndDate = Sheets("Launch").Range("H11").Value     

    'Copy the data
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:K2").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:K16000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3")
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3:T3").Clear

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code copies A1:K2, then A3:K1600, I would assume your header is located in one of those ranges, change the ranges to copy to not include the header row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Offset and Resize, assuming A3 has the header.  Little unclear to be honest but this shows the principle.

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:K16000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
   .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3")
End With
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: I keep getting this error. 'This action won't work on multiple selections'. It was working perfect perfect before.

Comment: What does debug.print Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:K16000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Address give you?

Comment: It was giving me Error: 'This action won't work on multiple selections